# Passing 2 arrays/collections laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hey guys I am passing an array like this, in a controller function: `return (['list_competencias' => $list_competencias]);`

I want to add a second array, but this does not work:`return (['list_competencias' => $list_competencias, 'all_users' => $all_users]);` 
How do I do return 2 arrays to my view??

I have seen other examples that use return view()->with(); I want to use the simple return I have because I dont see much of a difference between the 2..

Answer (score 0):

You should return `View` object:

```
return view('some.view', compact(list_competencias, 'all_users'));
```

Or:

```
return view('some.view', [
    'list_competencias' => $list_competencias,
    'all_users' => $all_users
]);
```

Comment: Or even `return view("some.view")->with(["x" => $x, "y" => $y]);`

Comment: Tim what is some.view? in my route I have define the route I am targeting as example 'return view('pages.view'); }) ->name('view');

Comment: Undefined variable: all_users

Comment: Do you set this variable in controller? If yes, please update your question with code from a controller and view.

Comment: Yes the variable i set it with  $all_users = User::all();

Comment: I also have the App\User; on top

Comment: Please post the code, I can't help you if I don't see the code.

Comment: `"some.view"` is a placeholder... I don't know the name of the view you want to return, so I used that. Replace it with the correct view (`.blade.php`) file in `resources/views`

Comment: return view("some.view")->with("list_competencias" => $list_competencias)->with( "all_users" => $all_users); Try this